# Android What is Difference between setVariable(BR.xyz, model) and databinding.setXYZ(model)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding

I was working on android data-binding and came across the scenario that we can set a model using following two ways:

```
 User user = new User("User", "Abc"); // this is a model
dataBinding.setVariable(BR.user, user);
dataBinding.executePendingBindings(); // and we have to do this... Why?
```

and we can also set like:

```
binding.setUser(user);
```

Can anyone explain this what the difference between these two?

**User Model:**

```
public class User{
public String fName;
public String lName;

public User(String fName, String lName){
this.fName = fName;
this.lName = lName;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Consider the case when you have a abstract class which does not share a common binding layout (except for of course the superclass `ViewDataBinding` which all binding layouts inherit from):

```
public abstract classs EditorActivityFragment<T extends ViewDataBinding> {
```

In this class' `onCreateView()` you won't be able to use any generated methods to set your variable to the binding, as there's no common superclass besides the ViewDataBinding, thus you will be forced to use reflection, or you can use the convenience method `setVariable()`:

```
binding.setVariable(BR.viewModel,myViewModel);
```

I hope that helps explain the use case for this method better.

Answer (score 11):

They do the same thing. According to [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ViewDataBinding.html#setVariable(int,%20java.lang.Object)), sometimes the type of the variable can't be determined, so you will have to use the `setVariable()` method. Under normal circumstances, the `setX()` method(s) will be generated. You are better off using the generated methods.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link from official docs if anyone is still not clear.
Link to doc - Click [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ViewDataBinding#setvariable)!

An excerpt from the doc as shared by @JarettMillard

```
boolean setVariable (int variableId, 
            Object value)
```

Set a value in the Binding class.

Typically, the developer will be able to call the subclass's set method directly. For example, if there is a variable x in the Binding, a setX method will be generated. However, there are times when the specific subclass of ViewDataBinding is unknown, so the generated method cannot be discovered without reflection. The setVariable call allows the values of variables to be set without reflection.

Some more references from their official docs
[Link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/generated-binding#advanced_binding)!

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BindingHolder, position: Int) {
   item: T = items.get(position)
   holder.binding.setVariable(BR.item, item);
   holder.binding.executePendingBindings();
}
```

This is useful when you don't have access to a specific binding class but a more generic version, like [ViewDataBinding](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/databinding/ViewDataBinding) (which is like the base class of all bindings). In such a case, you can use this method to set a property, like in the above case we have used for item variable.