# Optimizing Parent Fragment for ViewModel and DataBinding in order to avoid boilerplate code

Tags: android, fragment, android-databinding, android-viewmodel, koin

I have a `ParentFragment` and a `ChildFragment`. They are working pretty fine.

My problem is that in the future I might create many child fragments and this makes me write this boilerplate code for every single child fragment. Thus, I would like to optimize my `ParentFragment` so that I do not have to write boilerplate code for every single new child framment I create in the future.

`ParentFragment`

```
abstract class ParentFragment<T: ViewDataBinding>: Fragment() {

    @LayoutRes
    abstract fun getLayoutResId(): Int

    protected lateinit var binding: T

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)

        return DataBindingUtil.inflate<T>(inflater, getLayoutResId(), container, false).apply { binding = this }.root
    }
```

`ChildFragment`

```
class ChildFragment: ParentFragment<FragmentChildBinding>() {

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        //THIS IS THE BOILERPLATE METHOD I AM TALKING ABOUT. 
        //I WOULD LIKE TO MOVE THIS CODE IN THE PARENTFRAGMENT
        initBinding() 
    }

    @LayoutRes
    override fun getLayoutResId() = R.layout.fragment_child

    fun initBinding() {
        val viewModel: ChildViewModel = getViewModel() //This method is from Koin
        binding.viewModel = viewModel
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this
    }
```

I tried to move this `initBinding` method code into `ParentFragment` but I got errors. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So, your current issue is that you want to make your `initBinding()` function common in such a way that all child fragment can access it.

Now issue is that logic inside `initBinding` comes with koin dependency that gets resolved dynamically. So, each child fragment may have different ViewModel instance.

---

There is one way you can resolve this problem:

Take your `ViewModel` object as method parameter so that you can inject it from your child fragment while having method in parent fragment. check out below how:

`initBinding()` Method in `ParentFragment` with `viewModel` as method parameter that we will pass on from child fragments.

```
abstract class ParentFragment<T: ViewDataBinding>: Fragment() {

    // Other stuffs removed for sack of simplicity

    protected fun initBinding(viewModel: ViewModel) {
        binding.viewModel = viewModel
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this
    }
}
```

Accessing it from `ChildFragment`:

```
class ChildFragment: ParentFragment<FragmentChildBinding>() {

    // Other stuffs removed for sack of simplicity

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        // THIS IS HOW YOU CAN CONSUME THIS METHOD
        initBinding(getViewModel()) 
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot access `binding.viewModel` variable. I think, it is because binding does not yet know that it has a field with name `viewModel`. What do you think?

Comment: Oh!, clearly that's the thing I completely missed. Let me come up with another idea then.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call [`serVariable()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ViewDataBinding.html#setvariable) on your `binding` object to set `ViewModel` in the parent Fragment. Optionally in your parent Fragment you can get ViewModel through abstract function if child Fragments have their own ViewModels.

You can follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37367782/5465447) to solve your problem.

Comment: If I do this, code is running fine but my `data binding` is not working. Changing variable value in the `ViewModel` is not getting updated in the view.

Comment: I will create another question and send here the link. Because I think the problems are the seprate one.

Comment: Please check it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59283991/databinding-is-not-working-if-setvariable-method-is-used-to-set-viewmodel