# DataBinding is not working if setVariable() method is used to set ViewModel

Tags: android, android-databinding, koin

I have `ParentFragment` and `ChildFragment`. I am using Koin for DI.

In one case, data binding is not working and in another it is working.

**NOT WORKING CASE:** `ParentFragment`

```
abstract class ParentFragment<T: ViewDataBinding, V: ParentViewModel>: Fragment() {

    @LayoutRes
    abstract fun getLayoutResId(): Int

    abstract fun init()

    protected lateinit var binding: T

    protected abstract val mViewModel: V

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)

        return DataBindingUtil.inflate<T>(inflater, getLayoutResId(), container, false).apply { binding = this }.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        doDataBinding()
    }

    private fun doDataBinding() {
        binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner 
        binding.setVariable(BR.viewModel, mViewModel)
        binding.executePendingBindings()
        init()
    }
```

`ChidlFragment`

```
class ChildFragment: ParentFragment<FragmentChildBinding, ChildViewModel>() {

    @LayoutRes
    override fun getLayoutResId() = R.layout.fragment_child

    override val mViewModel: ChildViewModel by viewModel()

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    }

    override fun init() {
         mViewModel.a()
    }
```

`a()` method does nothing except changing the variable value to some random text. This varibale is bound to `EditText` in `ChildFragment`. These are basic data binding stuff. Implementation of this method is provided at the end of the question.

The code above working and `a()` method is being correctly called **but** `EditText` **value in my ChildFragment is not changing**.

**WORKING CASE:** If I change my code to this, everything is working fine.

`ParentFragment`

```
abstract class ParentFragment<T: ViewDataBinding>: Fragment() {

    @LayoutRes
    abstract fun getLayoutResId(): Int

    protected lateinit var binding: T


    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)

        return DataBindingUtil.inflate<T>(inflater, getLayoutResId(), container, false).apply { binding = this }.root
    }
```

`ChildFragment`

```
class ChildFragment: ParentFragment<FragmentChildBinding>() {

    @LayoutRes
    override fun getLayoutResId() = R.layout.fragment_child

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val viewModel: ChildViewModel = getViewModel()
        binding.viewModel = viewModel
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this

        binding.viewModel.a()

    }
```

My `ChildViewModel` class. Note this class is the same in both of the cases:

```
class ChildViewModel(): ParentViewModel() {
    var password: String = ""

    //This function is being called in both cases. BUT ONLY IN THE SECOND CASE, setting value
    //to "password" is being shown in the "EditText". 
    fun a () {
        Log.d("-------", "ViewModel method called")
        password = "asdasijdj1n2"
    }
}
```

What might the problem here?

The reason why I doing this is that I would like to optmize my `ParentFragment` as much as possible in order to avoid boilerplate code in the children fragments.

Comment: What's the actual question? `binding.viewModel = viewModel` this binds the view model to the layout, which you don't have as far as I can see in the case where it doesn't work. That's why as far as I can tell it doesn't work. In other words, where do you assign `protected lateinit var binding: T` in option1?

Comment: @Fred Question is why **Case 1** is not working. Please have a closer look at the code. `protected lateinit var binding: T` is assigned in the `onCreateView` of the `ParentFragment`.

Comment: I am guessing the method `setVariable()` in Case 1 has some issues.

Comment: Oh right, that completely escaped me. I actually always used approach 2 and never tried approach 1, because I thought the child classes would like to set different variables and not just viewmodels. But you are right, this should work.

Comment: The code in the working case doesn't call `executePendingBindings`. What happens if you change it to do that, before calling `binding.viewModel.a()`?

Comment: @clownba0t Sorry, but I could not get your point quite well. You mean I should call `executePendingBindings` in Case 2 (working case)?

Comment: Give it a try and see what happens - I'd be interested to know if the text still appears properly. If not, I suspect the root cause of the issue is related to timing (and the fact `password` is not a `LiveData` or `ObservableField`).

Comment: @clownba0t Ok. I removed `executePendingBindings` from **NOT WORKING CASE**. Surpisingly it is working. Please, write an answer so that I can accept your answer. Also, question: If I am gonna use `LiveData` instead of variables, do you think this isses appears again?

Comment: @clownba0t checked with `LiveData` as well, and it is working!

Comment: If you have a property in a view model used by databinding and the value of it can change, in the vast majority of cases I think you should be using `LiveData` or `ObservableField`. Furthermore, I think the root cause of the issue you're seeing is exactly this, and not whether you're calling `executePendingBindings` or not.

Comment: @clownba0t Totally agree )) I relatively new to DataBinding+ViewModels+LiveData+MVVM. Thus, I have not had a chance yet to dig deeper. You saved my day. Again, write an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues here, but only one is the root cause.

The reason the working case, well, works, is because the value of the `password` property in the view model is set before databinding actually binds it to the view. The reason this doesn't happen in the not working case is nothing to do with the structure of your fragments - it's simply that `binding.executePendingBindings()` is called before the value of `password` is set in the view model. This forces databinding to bind the value of `password` to view, but as it's `null` at the time, you don't see anything.

This brings us to the root cause of the issue, which is that you have a property in your view model which is being used by databinding and for which the value changes, but that property is not observable. Databinding needs to know when the value of properties it's using change, so that it can update the views that use those properties. The reason the not working case doesn't work is that databinding was forced to bind the `null` value for `password` to the view when `binding.executePendingBindings()` was called, and had no way of knowing that `password` was changed later, so it couldn't update the view.

Two ways to make properties observable by databinding are to declare them as `LiveData<T>` or `ObservableField<T>` instead of `T` (where `T` is the type of data). If `password` had been declared as a `MutableLiveData<String>` or an `ObservableField<String>`, you would have seen the value appear in the view in both cases in your question. This is because databinding would know when the value had changed.

So, in summary, it's good practice to use `LiveData` or `ObservableField` for properties declared in view models that are used in databinding and for which the value can change. That way, there's no potential for timing issues with things like when databinding binds values to views.

Comment: Great explanation! Now more clear why this wierd issue was happening

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem via provide view model for each child fragments. You can change

```
abstract class ParentFragment<T: ViewDataBinding, V: ParentViewModel>:Fragment() {

    abstract fun provideViewModel(): V

    protected lateinit var binding: T

    protected abstract val mViewModel: V

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)

        return DataBindingUtil.inflate<T>(inflater, getLayoutResId(), container, false).apply { binding = this }.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        doDataBinding()
    }

    private fun doDataBinding() {
        binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner 
        binding.setVariable(BR.viewModel, provideViewModel().apply { mViewModel = this})
        binding.executePendingBindings()
        init()
    }
```

in Child Fragments;

```
class ChildFragment: ParentFragment<FragmentChildBinding, ChildViewModel>() {

...

override val mViewModel: ChildViewModel by viewModel()

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

}

override fun provideViewModel() = mViewModel

...
```

}

Comment: should I define it as var? @issamux

Comment: maybe i m wrong but  by viewModel() can't be used with var and it doesn't even compile in Android studio!! does this work for you?
i m using koin androidx 2.1.5

Comment: you must define it as val because of lazy initialization by viewModel(). But i couldn't understand your first comment :) @issamux

Comment: :) ok . so now are you agree with me that we can't in this case define it as val  ! ?

Comment: ok i understood now :) you can not use in this case. I didn't pay attention that viewmodel is abstract. thank you :)